# Get output of variable followed by percent symbol batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am creating a script which will send an mail whenever disk space reaches a threshold value. I found one simple tool for getting space usage of disk drives. But I want to filter the output and place a condition for drive exceeding a defined threshold.

Using psinfo.exe tool, i am able to get disk usage output. Further I want to only fetch the numbers that are followed by percent symbol (%) in below output and place a condition for free space exceeding threshold.

```
Volume Type       Format     Label                      Size       Free   Free
   C: Fixed      NTFS       OS                    181.62 GB   91.69 GB  50.5%
   D: Fixed      NTFS       New Volume            273.90 GB  183.22 GB  66.9%
```

Would you please help me complete script.

Comment: Edit your question and post what did you tried as code until now !

Answer (score 0):

In case your disk labels do not contain spaces or dots you can try this:

```
@echo off

set "threshold=50"

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,11,12 delims=:.%% " %%a in ('psinfo') do (
    echo -%%a-%%b-%%c-
    if %%b geq %threshold% (
        echo disk %%a exceeds the threshold %threshold%
        echo free disk space is %%b.%%c%%
        echo some other code here
    )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick support @npocmaka.. but you can see in my output it has label with a space :(... Any other solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "treshold=50"

for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('psinfo') do (
   set "disk="
   for %%b in (%%a) do (
      if not defined disk set "disk=%%b"
      set "percent=%%b"
   )
   set /A "num=percent,num=num*10+!percent:~-2,1!"
   if !num! gtr %treshold%0 (
      echo Disk !disk! exceed %treshold%%%: !percent!
   )
)
```